# Wordpress htaccess rediret from http to https for single page

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have my http page to https. The page I want to change is http://dtesolar.ca/estore

I wish I could have https instead of http. I already purchase the ssl certificate, I'm using HTTPS plugin for wordpress but it's not working, so I'm thinking to use the .htaccess file to do it, but not sure for the syntax.

Here's the default thing on htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force HTTPS for store
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^estore/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**PS: You will need to fix links for your JS, css and images on this https URL.**

Comment: Thanks for replying. How to fix the links?

Comment: Well https page should use CSS, js files using https only.

Comment: Where should I modify that?

Comment: That would be in your WP theme files.

Comment: could u give me more detail info about that? Thanks!

Comment: You can search Google for that. see this tutorial: http://www.presscoders.com/wordpress-theme-customization-guide/